# Bind Data to Gridview Fixed Rows, Variable Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to write a web application to gather user counts for auditing purposes.  I have an Oracle query that works (I run it in SQL Developer), but I am trying to provide this report via web for superusers to pull their own counts instead of relying on me.  I am having trouble displaying the data in the gridview.

Oracle Query (with hard coded fixed amount of users):

```
select * from (
select ad.display_name, ev.creator from auditdefinition ad, event ev 
where ad.event_class_id = ev.object_class_id and ev.create_date >= to_date('01-OCT-2014','dd-MON-yyyy') and ev.create_date < to_date('01-DEC-2014','dd-MON-yyyy')
)
pivot 
(
count(creator)
for creator in ('user1','user2','user3','user4')
)
order by display_name;
```

Results Displayed something like:

```
------------------------------------------
|        | user1 | user2 | user3 | user4 |
------------------------------------------
| Create | 5     | 2     | 8     | 15    |
------------------------------------------
| Delete | 9     | 6     | 10    | 1     |
------------------------------------------
| View   | 123   | 461   | 84    | 89    |
------------------------------------------
***note:  Create, Delete, View are from "display_name" from the query
```

I know how to do it when the "Columns" are fixed (I did another table with a different query), but because I do not know how many "userX" there will be, I do not know how to build that dynamically in the web and display it in the grid.

aspx code for GridView:

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" GridLines="none" HorizontalAlign="Left" ID="GridView2" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs code behind scenes:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("Amount");
//I would normally add my columns here if they were fixed but because it it dynamic, I am not sure



...

GridView2.DataSource = dt; //beginning to bind my DataTable
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Dang, rookie mistake...I didn't even notice the AutoGenerateColumns attribute.  I had copied my gridview from my first one that has fixed number of columns and didn't notice it.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: How would I create my "columns" for the DataTable dynamically when I do not know how many Users the person is entering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you say `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` in your GridView control you need to specify the `Columns` tag with all the columns and their respective data values. Since you said you don't know how many "userX" will be there, let GridView control bind the data for you, Just pass the data you wish to see in GridView properly to the DataTable\ DataSet and set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to `true`:-

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="True" CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" GridLines="none" HorizontalAlign="Left" ID="GridView2" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

**Update:-**

You can fetch and fill the dataset directly using `dataadapter`:-

```
string CS = "Your connection string";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SPName", conn);
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@yourParam", SqlDbType.Int/*Your datatype*/).Value = 123;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView2.DataSource = ds;
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I changed it to "true", but I am still having trouble with the DataTable creating the "Columns" for the users from the query.  I haven't figured out how to do this dynamically because it gives me "Input Array is longer than the number of columns in this table." I suspect (pretty sure) it is because of the DataTable.

Comment: @Jayarikahs - Why you wanna fill it manually if your columns are not fixed? You can use `DataAdapter` to fill it for you.

Comment: I had to switch the SqlDataAdpater with Oracle because that is my backend.  I did test it out and it works!  Removing the DataTable and just using the DataSet solved the issue for me.  Thanks again for helping pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If user1, user2 and usern can be read from a table say tb_users, it would make your script easier.

```
select * from (
select ad.display_name, ev.creator from auditdefinition ad, event ev 
where ad.event_class_id = ev.object_class_id and 
ev.create_date >= to_date('01-OCT-2014','dd-MON-yyyy') and 
ev.create_date < to_date('01-DEC-2014','dd-MON-yyyy'))
pivot 
(
count(creator)
for creator in (select username from tb_users)
)
order by display_name;
```

If you do this, have a dropdown on the web form and bind it to the table tb_users

On select event of this dropdown you can bind your gridview with data selected with respect to the user.

Comment: My users do not exist in a separate table.  When a user performs an action, it is audited and a record gets created in my "event" table that stores the username in the "creator" column.